# How can I rotate and animate a MDLabel on adifferent axis?

Tags: python-3.x, animation, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I have this code that creates a `MDLabel` with `ButtonBehavior` and `RotateBehavior`.
When the `rotate_value_angle` is set to 0, I can animate the `MDLabel`'s height from 500 to 250.
When I change the angle to 90, the `MDLabel` rotates anti-clockwise, as expected.

The problem I'm experiencing is that with the `rotate_value_angle` at 90 degrees,
both the height and width of the `MDLabel` are animated. I want to animate the `MDLabel`'s
'height', which would be the left side of it, to move from left to right
while maintaining its anchor point at the bottom-right corner.

Essentially, the movement of the `MDLabel` should be similar to the movement when
the `rotate_value_angle` is set at 0 but with the phone tilted 90 degrees anti-clockwise.

Thanks in advance.

Here's my Kivy

```
MDScreen:
    RotateLabel:
        id: label
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 300, 500
        pos: 210, 470
        text: "Hello World!"
        on_release: app.change_rotate(self)
        md_bg_color: "red"
```

Python

```
class RotateLabel(ButtonBehavior, RotateBehavior, MDLabel):
    pass

class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):

        return Builder.load_string(kv)

    def change_rotate(self, instance_button: RotateLabel) -> None:
        # angle = choice([i * 45 for i in range(8)])

        anim = Animation(
            # rotate_value_angle = 0
            rotate_value_angle = 90, 
            d = 1)
        
        anim.bind(on_start = self.change_label_height)

        anim.start(instance_button)

    def change_label_height(self, *args):
        label = self.root.ids.label

        if label.size == [300, 500]:
            anim = Animation(
                height = 250,
                d = 2
            )

            anim.start(label)
        else:
            anim = Animation(
                height = 500,
                d = 2
            )

            anim.start(label)

Test().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that `RotateBehavior` rotates the widget about its center, which causes the behavior you are seeing. There doesn't seem to be any way to change the rotation origin when using `RotateBehavior`. You can change your `RotateLabel` definition  without using `RotateBehavior` like this:

```
class RotateLabel(ButtonBehavior, MDLabel):
    rotate_value_angle = NumericProperty(0)
    rot_matrix = ObjectProperty(Matrix())

    def on_rotate_value_angle(self, *args):
        self.rot_matrix.identity()
        self.rot_matrix.rotate(radians(-self.rotate_value_angle), 0, 0, 1)

    def collide_point(self, x, y):
        if self.rotate_value_angle == 0:
            return super(RotateLabel, self).collide_point(x, y)
        else:
            x1 = x - self.x
            y1 = y - self.y
            x2, y2, z2 = self.rot_matrix.transform_point(x1, y1, 0)
            x3 = x2 + self.x
            y3 = y2 + self.y
            return self.x <= x3 <= self.right and self.y <= y3 <= self.top
```

The above code handles the rotation and modifies the `collide_point()` method (which is used for button clicks) to account for the rotation.

The `kv` must also be modified for this to work:

```
MDScreen:
    RotateLabel:
        id: label
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 300, 500
        pos: 210, 470
        text: "Hello World!"
        on_release: app.change_rotate(self)
        md_bg_color: "red"
        canvas.before:
            PushMatrix:
            Rotate:
                angle: self.rotate_value_angle
                axis: 0, 0, 1
                origin: self.pos
        canvas.after:
            PopMatrix:
```

The above code does the rotation about the `pos` of the `RotateLabel` instead of its center.